# Error mongoose validation - Error "coleccion" mongoose validation failed: _id: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, validationerror

Estoy realizando un CRUD en node.js y usando mongoose pero al momento de registrar un articulo el cual tiene 3 campos que son de tipo objectId los cuales les ingreso el id correspondiente, el problema es que al intentar guardar mis datos en la base de datos obtengo un error de

> Error: Article validation failed: _id: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined

El cual no logro encontrar la solución ya trate de recrear la base de datos ingresando nuevos campos y modificando la estructura de mi petición pero no lo consigo

```
Este es mi modelo

    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniquevalidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

// Json to create a document for the database in mongoose
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre del articulo es requerido'],
        maxlength: [50, "El nombre de producto es muy largo"],
        trim: true,

    },
    model: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El modelo es requerido'],
        maxlength: [20, "El modelo es muy largo"],
        trim: true,

    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
    
    },
    
    provider: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Provider",
    
    },
    registerUser: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
   
    },
    levelStock: {
        type: String,
        default: "Alto",
        enum:["Alto","Medio"],
        required: true,
        trim: true,
       
    },
  
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
    },
    codeQR: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: [60, "El codigo de producto es muy largo"],
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        min: [0, "No puede haber numeros negativos"]
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
}, 
{
    collection: "Article",
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at",
    },
});
ArticleSchema.plugin(uniquevalidator, {
    message: '{PATH} Debe ser unico y diferente'
});
const Article = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
module.exports = Article;
```

Esta es mi petición, ya comprobé que el _id el cual recibo del usuario mediante el token no sea el problema ya que si me manda el registro mediante un consolé.log lo visualice

```
const createArticle = async (req, res) => {
  const { user, ...body } = req.body;

    const articleDB = await Article.findOne({ name: body.name });
    try {
        if (articleDB) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: `El articulo  ${articleDB.name}, ya existe`
            });
        }
        const data = {
            ...body,
            user: req._id
        }
        const newArticle = new Article(data);

        await newArticle.save();

        res.status(201).json(newArticle);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            error: 'No se ha podido registrar el articulo'
        });

}}
```

Por ultimo anexo una foto del error de forma mas especifica la linea que me marca erro de mi controlador es en el catch pero no logro entender porque marca ahí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo pudiste resolver? Cuando creas un articulo el la propiedad `_id` no debería existir en tus datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontre fue eliminar el plugin de mongoose

```
ArticleSchema.plugin(uniquevalidator, {
message: '{PATH} Debe ser unico y diferente'
```

});

Al quitar eso pude continuar el proyecto